# Nested dynamic array rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, multidimensional-array

I have created an array

```
steps = [{'title' =>'abc','content' =>'click this', 'target' => 'bca'}]
tours = ['id'=>'tour', 'steps:' => "#{steps}"]
puts tours
```

Getting following output :

```
{"id"=>"tour", "steps:"=>"[{\"title\"=>\"abc\", \"content\"=>\"click this\", \"target\"=>\"bca\"}]"}
```

The structure of the output is right but i don't want these `\` in the output.
What should i do to remove these `\`.
Thanks!

Comment: That's called [`escaping`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Зелёный` has the direct answer for you, however, there's a more pressing issue I would point out -- I think you're getting confused between `{hashes}` and `[arrays]`

--

An array is a set of unordered data:

```
array = [3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 5, 3, "cat", "dog"]
```

Arrays are mainly used for non-sequential collections of data, a good example being `product_ids` in a shopping cart.

Arrays can only be identified by using the location of the data inside the array:

```
array[1] # -> 4
array[2] # -> 5
```

--

A hash is a collection of `key:value` pairs:

```
hash = {name: "Greg", type: "cat"}
```

Hashes are used when you wish to assign multiple values to a single piece of data, and can be called by referencing the "key" of the hash:

```
hash["name"] #-> Greg
hash["type"] #-> cat
```

---

Whilst you can create an array of hashes:

```
 hash_array = [{name: "Greg", type: "cat"}, {name: "Sulla", type: "Dog"}]
```

... the problem with this is that you cannot call the hashes directly - they have to be *through* the array:

```
 hash_array["name"] # -> error
 hash_array[0]["name"] #-> "Greg"
```

---

Thus, I'd use the following in your example:

```
steps = {'title' =>'abc','content' =>'click this', 'target' => 'bca'}
tours = {id: 'tour', steps: steps}
tours.inspect #-> { id: "tour", steps: { "title" => "abc", "content" => "click this", "target" => "bca" }
```

Answer (score 2):

In ruby `"#{}"` invoke the `to_s` method on the object. You can check it run the following code: `steps.to_s`.

Just use:

```
tours = ['id'=>'tour', 'steps:' => steps]
```

Because this:

```
"[{\"title\"=>\"abc\", \"content\"=>\"click this\", \"target\"=>\"bca\"}]"
```

is a string representation of:

```
[{'title' =>'abc','content' =>'click this', 'target' => 'bca'}]
```

Comment: It's Rails way of outputting a legit string with escaped characters